# Use homebrew to install encfs on macOS?

Tags: macos, homebrew, encfs

I'd like to use homebrew to install [encfs](https://github.com/vgough/encfs) on macOS. Ideally, this would look like:

```
brew install macfuse
brew install encfs
```

As of macOS 12/Monterey, the first command works, but the second one does not, yielding†:

```
$ brew install encfs
Error: encfs has been disabled because it requires closed-source macFUSE!
```

How can I install encfs using homebrew?

---

† There is an inherent irony here in that we *can* directly install macfuse, but *can't* directly install another library dependent on (closed-source) macfuse. If I understand correctly, this happens because macfuse is distributed as a binary, and therefore it's formula is allowed in the official [homebrew-cask](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask). encfs is not distributed as a binary, and therefore is not allowed in homebrew-cask, and must remain in the more stringently-ruled [homebrew-core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core); thus the error message. Whew!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the homebrew cask found [here](https://github.com/gromgit/homebrew-fuse) to accomplish this, like so:

```
brew tap gromgit/fuse && brew install encfs-mac
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. :)